# Include 3rd party css in ionic2

Tags: css, ionic2

How to include a 3rd party css in ionic2? I guess it is probably linked to webpack config but I can't find any example anywhere, does someone know? for example, adding `font-awesome` css file after `npm install font-awesome`

Comment: Your question very useful, Thanks

Comment: @core114 yes, although with latests version of Ionic its completely different

Comment: Yes sir, im used for Ionic 3,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are interested in this, you can just add the files in the build process in the `ionic.config.js` like:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    sass: {
        src: [
          'app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss',
          'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'
        ],
        dest: 'www/build/css',
        include: [
          'node_modules/ionic-framework',
          'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
          'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
        ]
      },
      fonts: {
          src: [
            'node_modules/ionic-framework/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)',
            'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)'
          ],
          dest: 'www/build/fonts'
      }
      ...
}
```

This will compile `font-awesome.css` under `www/build/css` and fonts under `www/build/fonts`

Comment: I change the fonts line to
'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)'
it works.

Answer (score 3):

`ionic.config.js` has been deprecated.

**The correct answer is now:**

`npm install font-awesome`
Then edit your `gulpfile.js` to add options to the sass and fonts tasks:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return buildSass({
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [
        'node_modules/ionic-angular',
        'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
      ]
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('fonts', function(){
  return copyFonts({
    src: [
      'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)',
      'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*.+(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)'
    ]
  });
});
```

You can find more information on the gulp tasks here: [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-gulp-tasks](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-gulp-tasks.).

Then you should be able to `@import "font-awesome"` in your `app/theme/app.core.scss` file and use it in your project wherever.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the update. Maybe you could specify in which version it has been deprecated? also your link seems to be broken

Comment: Actually, not 100% sure when this changed ... beta 4?

Comment: thx you so much @rfornal. was struggling with cropperjs, same piece of code worked  perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can normally put css files in the index.html page and just use the css classes wherever you want. By default, your components are not completely isolated from the outside world so you should be able to use lets say bootstrap without any problems

Comment: the question is how to include files that are in the `node_modules` directory, and how to make it so that I don't have to manually copy the files that I want in the `www` folder, which breaks the build system. Anyways, I found out how to do it eventually